# asyncio + aiohttp : why is my client still a blocking?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to test my python 3.4.3 http client or application that sends HTTP requests to a server.  If the server to have a delay to respond for whatever reason, I'm expecting the requests should not be blocking as asyncio+aiohttp should provide asynchronous calls:

```
def post(self):
    print("received post")
    print(self.request)
    print("POST Body: %s" % str(self.request.body))
    time.sleep(3)
    self.write("blah")
    self.finish()
```

I'm just wondering why my code/http client is blocking:

```
import aiohttp, asyncio, async_timeout

@asyncio.coroutine
def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(30):
        try:
            response = yield from session.get(url)
            print((yield from response.read()))
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        finally:
            try:
                response.release()
            except:
                pass

@asyncio.coroutine
def post(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(30):
        try:
            response = yield from session.post(url)
            print((yield from response.read()))
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        finally:
            try:
                response.release()
            except:
                pass

@asyncio.coroutine
def close_connection(session):
    try:
        session.close()
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop)
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            html = loop.run_until_complete(post(session, 'http://localhost:8000'))
    except Exception as e:
        print("received exception %s." % type(e).__name__)

        # Close session if not closed.
    loop.run_until_complete(close_connection(session))
```

I tried to do a loop where i iterate through 10 URLs (its the same one here).  If it were sequential i would expect it to take ~30 seconds (server responds with 3 second delay).  With asynchronous, my expectation is that it takes less.

```
try:
    for i in range(10):
        html = loop.run_until_complete(post(session, 'http://localhost:8000'))
```

Is it the "run_until_complete()" function that is blocking?  How do I make it non-blocking?

Comment: It's better if you can elaborate on the expected behavior. Is it you mean the `loop.run_until_complete(close_connection(session))` is not executed concurrently along with `loop.run_until_complete(post(session, 'http://localhost:8000'))`?

Comment: Updated description.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when you use the `run_until_complete()`, you are telling the event loop to run the coroutine(s) passed as argument and return the result upon completion. In short, `run_until_complete()` will block until it finishes that operation.

Based on your for loop code snippet. Basically in every loop, the `run_until_complete` will block, run the coroutine (`post` in this context), return the result, then only the execution will continue for the next loop.

What you wanted to do here is to run all the `post` concurrently. What you can do is to use `asyncio.gather()`.

```
try:
    html = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[post(session, 'http://localhost:8000') for i in range(10)]))
```

Comment: This is the error I got:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 48, in <module>
    html = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather([post(session, 'http://localhost:8000')]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 565, in gather
    for arg in set(coros_or_futures):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Fixed. Forgot to unpack the list

Comment: Thanks!  I want to understand, this is through passing a list.  Is there a way to make aiohttp 'fire and forget'?

Comment: @ozn Can you describe in more detail what you mean by "fire and forget" here?

Comment: Perhaps @ozn prefers unreliable programs :)

Comment: My mistake, I think I need to edit my description more; the post I made was only contains a smaller scope that I intended.  Essentially the stuff I have in the __main__ or (main()) is part of another method (lets call it make_a_post()) in a object (class).  When I call the <class instance>.make_a_post() 10 times sequentially it completes around ~30 seconds (3sec delay in server * 10 transactions).  I the components that calls the <object instance>.make_a_post() need to be asynchronously handled as well.
After research, yeah, fire and forget is little meaningless.

Comment: @ozn Is `make_a_post` a coroutine? `asyncio.gather`, as shown in this answer, runs the provided coroutines *in parallel*, so `asyncio.gather([self.make_a_post(...) for x in bla])` should do what you want.